# Replying to remoteinput

Tags: android, facebook, notifications, whatsapp, pushbullet

I've created a simple application which listens to notification events from other applications. I received StatusBarNotification object and got WearableExtender out of it. Then I got the remoteInputs that the extender was having.

Then used this code to fill remoteinput with my own text and sent the pendingIntent:

```
RemoteInput[] remoteInputs = new RemoteInput[notificationWear.remoteInputs.size()]; 
 Intent localIntent = new Intent();
 localIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
 Bundle localBundle = notificationWear.bundle;
  int i = 0;
 for(RemoteInput remoteIn : notificationWear.remoteInputs){ getDetailsOfNotification(remoteIn);
  remoteInputs[i] = remoteIn;
 localBundle.putCharSequence(remoteInputs[i].getResultKey(), "Our answer"); //This work, apart from Hangouts as probably they need additional parameter (notification_tag?)
 i++;
 }
 RemoteInput.addResultsToIntent(remoteInputs, localIntent, localBundle);
 try {
 notificationWear.pendingIntent.send(MainActivity.this, 0, localIntent);
 } catch (PendingIntent.CanceledException e) 
 { 
 Log.e(TAG, "replyToLastNotification error: " + e.getLocalizedMessage());
 }
```

However the source claims this code should work, I'm only able to open the specific application and specific conversation, but not able to send a reply.
I've tried it with Facebook, WhatsApp, and other apps. Same goes for other applications as well.